# Array power iteration

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I need to create several arrays from a vector x. Each element in the vector needs to be of the power 0,1,2,...,n. A array with 3 elements should yield 3 arrays, with power 0,1,2.

```
x=numpy.array([1,2,3])
n=len(x)
for i in range(n):
    print(x**i)
```

Yields:

```
[1 1 1]
[1 2 3]
[1 4 9]
```

When I would like to have:

```
array([1, 1, 1]),
array([1, 2, 3]),
array([1, 4, 9])
```

Comment: Just double-checking: do you want three separate 1D arrays, or one 2D array?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want a 2D numpy array containing all the raised numpy arrays:

```
import numpy
x=numpy.array([1,2,3])
print numpy.array([x**i for i in range(len(x))])
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. I have tried something similar to this, but probably not entirely. This solves my problem

```
x=numpy.array([1,2,3])
n=len(x)
f = []
for i in range(n):
    f.append(x**i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope following will work for you

```
x = np.arange(5)    
powr = [1,2,3]    
np.array([x**i for i in powr])

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16],
       [ 0,  1,  8, 27, 64]])
```

Answer (score 0):

What you print *are* `numpy` arrays, it's just that `print` uses the string representation as returned from the `str` builtin. What you want is the string returned by the `repr` builtin (see [Difference between **str** and **repr** in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python) for detailed discussion of the issues involved).

Try this code and appreciate the similarities and the differences

```
import numpy

x=numpy.array([1,2,3])
n=len(x)
for i in range(n):
    print(x**i)
    print(str(x**i))
    print(repr(x**i))
```